# Passing variables from route to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a big issue over here and I have no idea how to solve it.

**routes.php:**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user'), function() {

    Route::post('/{user}/{char_name}/selectedok', array(
        'as' => 'char-profile-post',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@postDropDownList'
    ));   

    Route::get('/{user}/{char_name}/selectedok', array(
        'as' => 'char-profile-get',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@getDropDownList'
    ));

});
```

**ProfileController.php:**

```
public function getDropDownList() {  

    return View::make('layout.profile');     

}



public function postDropDownList($user, $char_name) {

    if (Auth::check())
    {   
        $user = Auth::user();
        $selected_char = Input::get('choose');
        $char_name = User::find($user->id)->characters()->where('char_name', '=', $selected_char)->first();


        return Redirect::route('char-profile-get', array($user->username, $char_name->char_dynasty, $char_name->char_name))
                ->with('user', $user->username)
                ->with('charname', $char_name->char_name)
                ->with('dynastyname', $char_name->char_dynasty);



    }
}
```

Yes I know I redirect to `char-profile-get` with 3 parametres, but I only need 2. It doesn't bother me. As you observe, I redirect using `->with`. The only way I will print the data in the view is by doing this in the view:

Your chosen character is

```
{{ Session::get('charname') }} {{ Session::get('dynastyname')}}
```

If I don't overwrite the variables in `postDropDownList($user, $char_name)` my `URL` will literally look like this:

```
 http://localhost/CaughtMiddle/tutorial/public/index.php/user/%7Buser%7D/%7Bchar_name%7D/selectedok
```

instead of this:

```
 http://localhost/CaughtMiddle/tutorial/public/index.php/user/SerbanSpire/Spirescu/selectedok?Serban
```

So the verdict. The parameters in the functions will never receive any data. I don't even know how to describe them, the functions' parameters are null, even if I redirect to the get route with the correct data. `var_dump($user)` or `var_dump($char_name)` doesn't print anything on the browser, `dd($user)` and `dd($char_name)` also doesn't print anything nor does `print_r()`.

Is my solution a viable one? By redirecting using `->with` and storing the data in Session? Because this solution will drive me into using `Session::get()` a lot, every time I use information from the database, but i don't update it! Stop me if I am wrong.

Why aren't the variable's from the route going to the parameters of my functions? If my functions wouldn't have any parameters, the code would work the same. Basically, those parameters are there for nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel send variable to the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027764/laravel-send-variable-to-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally managed to resolve my issue. I have made a new CharacterController.php file and I put the get function inside the new controller. This way the function's parameters will successfully arrive and be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct you just need

```
        return Redirect::route('char-profile-get', array(
        'username' => $user->username,
        'char_name' => $char_name->char_name))
        ->with('user', $user->username)
        ->with('charname', $char_name->char_name)
        ->with('dynastyname', $char_name->char_dynasty);
```

because you pass an empty array.
now use Session::get('username') and Session::get('char_name') directly in the view (layout.profile)

Comment: public function getDropDownList($username, $char_name) {  
            
            
            return View::make('layout.profile')
                ->with('char_name', $char_name);
                

                         
        } the parametres are still empty in this function

Comment: You're wrong, learn laravel docs http://laravel.com/docs/responses. You get variable from air. You do not need the method's parameters and 'with' method on getDropDownList(). Variables that you pass with 'with' method may be retrieved with Session::get('passed_keyName') directly in the view untill you not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
$user = Auth::user();
$char = $user->characters()->where('char_name', Input::get('choose'))->first();

return Redirect::route('char-profile-get')
               ->with('user', $user->username)
               ->with('charname', $char->char_name)
               ->with('dynastyname', $char->char_dynasty);
```

Comment: It does the same thing. The URL is done correctly, but the get route  doesn't send any usable parametres to getDropDownList. var_dump($charname); doesn't do anything because this function's parametres' are basically null.

Comment: Actually, `with` just flashes data into `session` so make sure your session contains data by `{{ dd(Session::all()) }}` in the view.

Comment: Also your `getDropDownList()` doesn't accept any args, so don't pass any args.

Comment: I have tried that, but I will use Session::get() basically in the rest  of my project. I don't think I will ever use normal variables again. Is this a viable solution?

Comment: `Session::all()` returns everything from session and I told you to check the session by dumping the session.